# threejs video from youtube in 3D scene

Tags: three.js

I have a scene created from loaded models. There is tv on the scene. 
I want to add youtube player on the screen of the TV.

I use 
    THREE.WebGLRenderer for all models on the scene.
    THREE.CSS3DRenderer for iframe with youtube.

The problem is that screen size of TV model in webGL is too small (1.2x0.8), and I cannot fit iframe with youtube in TV screen.

How to set scale or units for iframe, or somehow set scale between webGL units and CSS3D pixels?

```
// creating css object    
function createCssObject(w, h, position, rotation, url) {
    var html = [
    '<div style="width:' + w + 'px; height:' + h + 'px;">',
    '<iframe src="' + url + '" width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '">',
    '</iframe>',
    '</div>'
    ].join('\n');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    var cssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject(div);
    cssObject.position.x = position.x;
    cssObject.position.y = position.y;
    cssObject.position.z = position.z;
    cssObject.rotation.x = rotation.x;
    cssObject.rotation.y = rotation.y;
    cssObject.rotation.z = rotation.z;
    return cssObject;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Do you have a working example so we can see the issue? Codepen, maybe?

Comment: I wanna give you idea : https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/vue-typescript-starter